# Modifying HTTP response headers in Firefox

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, http-headers, firefox-addon

Does anyone know if Firefox extensions are allowed to modify HTTP response headers? For example, can an extension remove the x-frame-options header to let the page load in an iframe?

Thanks

Comment: PourBico allows you to modify response headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S. Wong is correct.  Modify Headers supports modification of request headers only at present.  However, I am looking at supporting response headers for a future version.

Comment: There is a Firefox addon that was created for modifying CORS HTTP response headers but you can customize this headers in about:config/forcecors.headers, see https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/forcecors/

Answer (score 5):

I think the best firefox addon for modifying headers is TamperData :

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, TamperData, like ModifyHeaders can't modify HTTP response headers, only request headers.

Comment: Can't edit, but that link is dead. This looks to be a replacement: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/tamper-data-for-ff-quantum/ doesn't exactly look promising though.

Answer (score 2):

it's late but i found some thing, i was going through code of "temper data" extention and i was able to modify the response as:

```
  observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {

    if (aTopic == 'http-on-modify-request') {
        aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
        this.onModifyRequest(aSubject);
       }
}   


   onModifyRequest(oHttp){
     //this is how i modify the set-cookie field from header
      oHttp.setResponseHeader("Set-Cookie", enc, false);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Modify Response addon that is limited to Content-Type, but should be adaptable to all (most) others.

Answer (score 1):

Install [PourBico](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/pourbico/) for Firefox.

Open PourBico window.
Reload URL, modify the header, reload page.