# How to add mode: 'no-cors' to XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, cors, xmlhttprequest

I am new to JavaScript. How can I add mode: `no-cors` to my `XMLHttpRequest` in JavaScript?

For example, to this code:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", yourUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    value: value
}));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667512/using-xmlhttprequest-without-cors-by-modifying-http-headers

Answer (score 7):

`XMLHttpRequest` does not support `no-cors` mode, only `fetch` does.

However, you are trying set a `Content-Type` of `application/json` which **requires permission from CORS**, so you can't use `no-cors` mode anyway.

If you used `fetch` and set `no-cors` mode then the instruction to set the `Content-Type` would be ignored.

Instead, configure `yourUrl` to grant permission, using CORS, to make the request with the JSON `Content-Type`.

Comment: Thank you, so as I use fetch, I dont need to set  Content-Type? right?

Comment: you do if you want to send JSON in the request @разияУтегенова

Comment: Isn't `Content-Type` one of the [`no-cors` safelisted headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#no-cors-safelisted-request-header-name)? This is an area I don't know well, so I suspect I'm missing something.

Comment: Ah, it is safelisted -- but with only limited values, and `application/json` isn't one of them.

Comment: Actually, you can set `Content-Type` of `application/json` with mode `no-cors` - it sends content-type plain/text regardless as far as I can tell

Comment: You got there before I could find the reference: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header

Comment: @Bravo — If you give an instruction to set it to JSON and it ignores it and sends plain text, then it isn't setting it, is it?

Comment: @Quentin - I said "as far as I can tell" - it strikes me as odd that `no-cors` request would block sending JSON - I may be doing something wrong - or, as you say, setting it is "ignored"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I know too much about CORS (not everything of course, stupid JSON no-cors requests!) - for years I had to deal with fellow developers who just don't get the point of CORS and think "I can bypass this with trickery in the browser"

Comment: @Bravo — I believe the basic logic is that with a classical HTML form you can send any Content-Type supported by `enctype`. People writing web apis may have assumed that if the content-type was not one of those then it was safe from cross-origin attacks. So now, if you make a request with Ajax and you want to set a content-type that is not supported by `enctype` then you need permission from CORS. Using `no-cors` mode basically makes everything which requires permission from CORS to fail silently and without errors - including changing the content type from the default (plain text) to JSON.