# Web access HTML file in my Gitlab repo

Tags: html, git, gitlab, web-access

I want to use `Gitlab` to manage web-application development. Is it possible to access the `html` file I have created in my `Gitlab repo` from the browser?

Currently there are `ssh/http` url for access to the repo like:

```
ssh: git@something.some.ca:balbal/web-app.git   
http: (ht tps://something.some.ca:balbal/web-app.git)
```

When I access `https` from a browser it will just jump into the git repo manage UI (like show you all the commits, branches and detail files)

What I want is web access to a particular `html` file I have created in my repo (like if there is a `index.html` file in a folder called 'www' in my repo). I want some URL that I can type into the browser and which will show me the `index.html` content. 
Is it possible for me to set up an web access to these `html` files?

Comment: do you want to access the index html in code or you want the page rendered? If you just want to see the code, you can use the link provided by the raw button on your repo page

Comment: i want to render it out @ShaRanShade

Comment: I think a webserver will be needed if i want to render it out right? The question then becomes how to set connection between web server and gitlab repo...@ShaRanShade

Comment: sorry I was busy. After some searching, I think it's possible to have github host your index page. This article might have what you want. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-github-pages-to-host-your-website

Comment: @user3735448 could you please accept my answer, since it should be working for you?

Answer (score 8):

As of now, Gitlab does not support this functionality. There's a feature request for this: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/5599145-preview-render-static-html-pages-pushed-to-repos

Currently, if you query Gitlab for the raw html file, it sets certain HTTP headers to make it render as text/plain instead:

```
$ curl -I http://my-gitlab/user/project/raw/dev/doc/_book/index.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 13:17:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="index.html"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Cache-Control: private
ETag: "b81191c550c47eae1ab4adf72dfd0c92"
Set-Cookie: request_method=HEAD; path=/
X-Request-Id: 04ae0499-2fdf-4f89-82ab-8392a8d6a076
X-Runtime: 0.019857
```

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately, with GitLab 10.1, online display of HTML files is now officially supported.

See the [documentation](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/10/22/gitlab-10-1-released/#online-view-of-html-artifacts) for more details.

> With GitLab 10.1, we introduce the online visualization of HTML files created by pipelines for public projects, just one click away from the artifacts browser view.

Comment: Well... that doesn't seem to be working today on gitlab.com :-(

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a file called `.gitlab-ci.yml` at the root of your project containing

```
pages:
 script:
 - mkdir .public
 - cp -r * .public
 - mv .public public
 artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
 only:
 - master
```

Then access your file there: `https://gitlab.org/project-name/filename.html`

Source: https://roneo.org/en/framagit-render-html/

**Update:** see also the project [raw.githack](https://raw.githack.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For quick debugging/testing purposes you may use the FireFox [PourBico](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/pourbico/) plugin.

[Change the response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537262/modifying-http-response-headers-in-firefox) to text/html

Avoid doing this on the public GitLab, do this on your own GitLab deployment, GitLab was not meant to be hacked like this.

Also see [Github pages, HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798589/github-pages-http-headers)

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome, one can use extensions such as [Header Hacker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/header-hacker/phnffahgegfkcobeaapbenpmdnkifigc?hl=en) and set the headers to render HTML by changing the content-type in the browser. As mentioned by Christophe Roussy this is a hack and you should really have a good reason for doing this.